# How to config symfony to log deprecations?

Tags: php, symfony, monolog, deprecation-warning

I'd like to upgrade from Symfony 4.4. to 5.0. So I have to check for deprecations in the code. The symfony [migration guide](https://symfony.com/doc/master/setup/upgrade_major.html#make-your-code-deprecation-free) says I have to use the web dev toolbar, but in my API-app there is no frontend for the tool-bar.

How can I configure symfony/monolog to log deprecation warnings to the log file?

**Update**
I have created a minimal example:

```
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton:4.3.99
```

TestController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class ApiController
 * @package App\Controller
 * @Route("", defaults={"_format"="json"})
 *
 */
class TestController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function test(Request $request): Response
    {
        @trigger_error(sprintf('DEMO DEPRECATION', __METHOD__), E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        return $this->json([
            'test' => '1'
        ]);
    }
}
```

monolog.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!event"]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type: firephp
        #    level: info
        #chromephp:
        #    type: chromephp
        #    level: info
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
        deprecation_stream:
              type: stream
              path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.deprecations.log"
        deprecation_filter:
             type: filter
             handler: deprecation_stream
             max_level: info
             channels: ["php"]
```

run server

```
 bin/console server:run
```

open http://localhost/test

But the dev.deprecations.log is still empty.

Comment: It seems that the debug toolbar in dev mode captures these deprecation notices, because they don't appear in the standard log file. I suspect a compiler pass is intercepting them.

Comment: I created a bug report / question on github https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in Symfony 4.4 which is now fixed. [More details here.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35367)

Answer (score 4):

This is my deprecation log configuration, using Monolog:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
  # other handlers...

    ### Deprecation logs
    deprecation_stream:
      type: stream
      path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.deprecations.log"

    deprecation_filter:
      type: filter
      handler: deprecation_stream
      max_level: info
      channels: ["php"]
```

The `deprecation_stream` specify a log file to log these messages.

The `deprecation_filter` specifies which messages should be logged: `info` messages happening in the `php` channel (this is where all deprecation log messages are sent).

You can enable this application wide, or only set it up this way in whatever environment you want to catch these messages.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for me. I have installed the dev-toolbar and created a demo controller. There I see the deprecation warnings, but no where else. I don't get it why the dev-toolbar can catch these warnings. I try to create a minimal example.

Comment: i have updated the question with an minimal example.