# Show container deprecation log in human-readable format?

Tags: symfony, symfony5, monolog, deprecation-warning

I have a Symfony 5.3 application. When the container is compiled, the following file appears:

> var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainerDeprecations.log

In contains a serialized list of deprecation messages:

```
a:13:{i:0;a:6:{s:4:"type";i:16384;s:7:"message";s:166:"Since symfony/security-guard 5.3: ...
```

Is there a way to display this deprecation log in human-readable format? I could not find a `bin/console` command to do that.

Also, is the output location/format of this deprecation log configured somewhere? It does not seem to follow the monolog config that applies to the rest of the project.

Comment: @yivi I found this link already, and it does not seem to answer my question. I have the monolog handlers set, but the file output during container compilation (`App_KernelDevDebugContainerDeprecations.log`) does not match the configured monolog file format `%kernel.environment%.deprecations.log`.

Comment: That's not the log. That's output for the profiler. It's on the cache directory, not on the log directory. If you want a deprecation log, use the directions in the linked QA. If you have already configured monolog to create a deprecation log and you are not getting, please edit your question to include your monolog configuration.

Comment: @yivi Interesting, thanks. Indeed, the deprecations are also reflected in the configured log file in the `log` directory.

Comment: @yivi Do you want to add the profiler information as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are seeing is not the deprecation log, but a serialized output that the Symfony Profiler will use to show this information on `dev`.

Notice that sits on the cache/build directory (`var/cache`), and not on the log directory (`var/log`).

To configure Monolog to log deprecations, use the directions you'll find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59455500/1426539), for example. You'll notice that the resulting log ends up where you point it to, and the result will be a regular log file in mostly readable format.